# How to change the ischecked state of a each element in a list of checkbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm defining a list of check boxes as follows:

```
<ListBox Name="listBoxZone" ItemsSource="{Binding Nr5GRRCList}" Background="Azure" Margin="346,93,89,492" Grid.Column="1">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBoxItem IsSelected="{Binding IsChecked}">
                <CheckBox x:Name="RRC5G_CheckBox" 
                      Content="{Binding messageType}" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                      Checked="RRC5G_CheckBox_Checked" 
                      Unchecked="RRC5G_CheckBox_Unchecked"
                      Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Where Nr5GRRCList related code is:

```
public ObservableCollection<BoolStringClass> Nr5GRRCList { get; set; }
public class BoolStringClass
{
    public string messageType { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}

if (Nr5GRRCList == null)
{
    Nr5GRRCList = new ObservableCollection<BoolStringClass>();
}

foreach(string filter in rrc5GFilters)
{
    Nr5GRRCList.Add(new BoolStringClass { messageType = filter, IsChecked = false });
}
```

This is working fine:
[image]

I'm trying to add an checkbox to control all checkboxes in this list:

- I'll still be able to check/uncheck the checkboxes individually
- I want to be able to check/uncheck the new checkbox and get all the checkboxes checked/unchecked

I tried adding the new checkbox:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox_NR5G_RRC" Content="RRC" Checked="HandleCheck_RRC5G" Unchecked="HandleUncheck_RRC5G" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Margin="334,76,341,607" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

[image]

I can't find a way of modifying the ischecked value of each individual checkbox when the 'RRC' is checked/unchecked. All I seem to have access to is a list of BoolStringClass elements.

Any tipd would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Images are not showing as I expected, the 'RRC' checkbox is the new checkbox I added to control all checkboxes in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All I seem to have access to is a list of BoolStringClass elements

that is all data you need.

```
foreach(BoolStringClass item in Nr5GRRCList)
{
    item.IsChecked = !item.IsChecked;
    // item.IsChecked = true;
    // item.IsChecked = false;
}
```

to see update in UI you need to add notifications in BoolStringClass, e.g by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public class BoolStringClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string messageType { get; set; }

    private bool _IsChecked;
    public bool IsChecked 
    {
        get { return _IsChecked; }
        set
        {
            _IsChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsChecked));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was missing